# Using Microsoft.Build.NoTargets getting ucrt path

Tags: msbuild

I have created an msbuild project which uses `Microsoft.Build.NoTargets` and I need to import `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\uCRT.props`

I would like to be able to use the builtin variable `$(UniversalCRT_PropsPath)` instead of the full path, however when using `Microsoft.Build.NoTargets` it is undefined.

Do I need to `Import` something else first?

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" Version="3.7.0" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.22621.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)'=='17.0'">v143</PlatformToolset>
    <Platforms>x64;x86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <Platform>x86</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <Platform>x86</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\uCRT.props"/>

  <Target></Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: `$(UniversalCRT_PropsPath)` is not a "built-in" property in MSBuild. (See "[MSBuild reserved and well-known properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022)" and "[Common MSBuild project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2022)".) I assume its definition is specific to The Univeral C Runtime.

Comment: A trick to help track down the property's definition: For a project that has the property, run `msbuild /preprocess` for the project and direct the output to a file. Then search the file for the property definition. There will be comments in the output indicating the source import file.